# Is json_decode parse-ability proof of a safe string?

Tags: security

Do I need to use check_plain (or something else) when displaying a user supplied JSON string, when I have previously checked it successfully parses with json_decode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: You should `check_plain` it.**

Because the json-enoded string itself can contain insecure code.

This is our example. `$data[1]` and `$data[2]` should not be executed.

```
$data = array(
  'Hukana Matata',
  '<script>alert("Oh no!")</script>',
  '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:alert(\"Oh no!\')">CLick here</a>',
);
```

You encode this with json_encode. If you `json_decode($data_str)`, and it's a perfectly valid `JSON`.

```
$data_str = json_encode($data);
```

Now, if you print this:

```
print $data_str;
```

Now, you will see that the forward slash is escaped.

```
["Hukana Matata","<script>alert(\"Oh no!\")<\/script>","<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"javascript:alert(\\\"Oh no!')\">CLick here<\/a>"]
```

json_encode encodes strings for JSON notation. In the example above, we encoded using json_encode from PHP's implementation. But depending on the [flags](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php), you can prevent PHP from doing do.

```
$data = array(
      'Hukana Matata',
      '<script>alert(document.title)</script>',
      '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:alert(\"Oh no!\')">CLick here</a>',
    );
$data_str = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
print $data_str;
```

Notice how the script tag sneaked in:

```
["Hukana Matata","<script>alert(document.title)</script>","<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"javascript:alert(\\\"Oh no!')\">CLick here</a>"]
```

Comment: Awesome answer. check_plain it is. (I assumed this was the case, but wanted a definitive answer, which this looks to be!). Thanks!